# Android chrome data saver-how it works

Tags: android, google-chrome-app

Can anyone please tell me how the chrome data saver encryption work
how server work in encrypting the data ,so that it size decrease

Comment: See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Answer (score 6):

I'm the lead on the Chrome Data Saver team. We have a detailed paper published on how Data Saver works here:

http://www.mdw.la/papers/flywheel-nsdi15.pdf

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

> When you use Data Saver, most of your web traffic goes through Google
>   servers before being downloaded to your device. Less data gets
>   downloaded to your device, because Google servers will compress it.
>
> Data Saver won't work if you're on secure pages (addresses that start
>   with https://) or if you're browsing in private with Incognito mode.

[Use less data with Chrome’s Data Saver](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Comment: but what is the technology behind it working on server

Comment: The question is about encryption

Comment: can you elaborate me with this type of encryption